# OCL Syntax Checker

Tags: java, syntax, open-source, uml

I have been looking for an existing open-source syntax-checker for the Object Constraint Language (OCL). I intend to extend the syntax-checker with additional functionality not present in the OCL standard to be more applicable to my usage with entity-relationship diagrams. However, most of the projects I have found are based on the Eclipse Meta-Object Facility (MOF), while I seek only the ability to verify the grammar of an OCL expression (completely independent of any associated class diagrams, etc.). I have begun looking into the source of the Dresden OCL Toolkit (dresden-ocl.sourceforge.net), even though the newest toolkit is also intended for use with the Eclipse MOF. Unfortunately, all downloads are blocked at the company I work for, and it takes 1-2 days minimum to get permission for any download, so I want to know if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction to find what I am looking for.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,

Shona

Answer (score 7):

I've been using Dresden OCL for quite a long time and I think it is a really good starting point for what you want (of course, it is not perfect, last time I checked it still had some problems with recognizing some set operators or navigation expression from association classes).

You can also take a look at the Eclipse OCL plug/in http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/downloads/?project=ocl
part of the model-development tools initiative

Pointers to other tools supporting OCL (not necessarily open-source) here: http://modeling-languages.com/content/list-ocl-tools

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm looking into the Eclipse OCL plugin, as you suggested I might do. Hopefully I'll be able to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you might by interested in having a look at other tools supporting OCL syntax checking, like [Octopus](http://www.klasse.nl/octopus/index.html), created(?) by Jos Warmer and Anneke Kleppe, who are authors of the OCL specs.